# Bold font not working with Helvetica

Tags: fonts, bold, italic, installing-fonts, helvetica

I'm trying to write my paper in the Helvetica font. For that I installed the package fontspec and \setmainfont{Helvetica}. But when using \textbf{} nothing happens. The same goes for \textit{}. What do I have to do in order to get these working?

Thanks for the help. I'm still learning the ropes of LaTeX.

```
   \documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

   \usepackage{fontspec}
   \setmainfont{Helvetica}

   \begin{document}

   In \textbf{Figure 1} something

   \end{document}
```

EDIT: I found my problem, I was using a lean Typsetter which didn't support it.

Comment: Welcome  to TeX.SE. Which operating system is on your computer? Which TeX distribution do you employ? When did you last update it? Do you employ XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX to compile your document? Which version of `fontspec` do you employ? (The most recent version is `2.8a`.)

Comment: Please provide `MWE` of your tag, refer the link https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/430/text-building-blocks regarding `MWE`

Comment: Just found my problem, I was using Texpad and their built-in Typesetter. When switching to MacTeX the problem solved itself.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP's issue was caused by a factor not discernible to readers. Once the OP started using MacTeX, the issue disappeared.

Answer (score 5):

The `fontspec` package is not able to guess the filenames of the other faces in the font family.  That you’re using Helvetica suggests that you might be on a Mac.  On MacOS, you might try the following (untested!)

```
\setmainfont{Helvetica}[
  UprightFont = {*},
  BoldFont = {* Bold},
  SlantedFont = {* Oblique},
  BoldSlantedFont = {* Bold Oblique}]
```

You might want to run `luaotfload-tool --find "Helvetica"` from the command line to test that LuaTeX has the font in its database, and `fc-match "Helvetica"` fron the command line to test that XeTeX can.  If so, you can then look in the same directory or search for "Helvetica Bold".

You might alternatively try a clone of Helvetica that is on your system.  TeX Gyre Heros is one that ships with TeX, but you might also have Helvetica Neue or Arial.

Just a guess:  I understand Big Sur now reserves the name Helvetica and does a substitution, so it’s possible that broke compatibility with TeX.  You might try the name of the font that is actually substituted (Try `luaotfload-tool --find "Helvetica" --fuzzy` to get likely suspects.)

If that’s Helvetica Neue, for example, you could possibly work around this by saving a command somewhat like this to a file named `Helvetica.fontspec` (again, untested):

```
\defaultfontfeatures[Helvetica]{
  UprightFont = {Helvetica Neue},
  BoldFont = {Helvetica Neue Bold},
  SlantedFont = {Helvetica Neue Oblique},
  BoldSlantedFont {Helvetica Neue Bold Oblique} ]
```

Comment: +1 for being a font detective :).

Answer (score 2):

I took this example from the testing files included in the package `helvet`.

(Tested as it is with pdflatex, and lualatex -- *without loading* `fontspec` --)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[scaled=0.92]{helvet}% install<<<<
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont

\begin{quote}
    \raggedright
    A regular f\'ee costs 1.23\,\texteuro.\\
    \textit{An italic f\'ee.costs 1.23\,\texteuro.}\\
    \textsl{A slanted f\'ee costs 1.23\,\texteuro.}\\
    \textsc{A SmallCaps f\'ee.}\\
    {\bfseries A bold f\'ee costs 1.23\,\texteuro.\\
        \textit{A bold italic f\'ee costs 1.23\,\texteuro.}\\
        \textsl{A bold slanted f\'ee costs 1.23\,\texteuro.}\\
        \textsc{A bold SmallCaps f\'ee.}\\
    }
\end{quote}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: a]

From [helvet – Load Helvetica](https://ctan.org/pkg/helvet?lang=en)  in CTAN.

Comment: This would only work with legacy 8-bit PostScript fonts.